# Ask for Spring Cloud Data Flow Security example

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have tried the SCDF Security with UAA + LDAP example ([link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example)).

However, Im looking for some more Security approaches while using SCDF local. It 'll be great if having example (source, document)

Comment: Please remember that `local` flavor of SCDF is not recommended for production and intended to be used for development/debugging purposes. Hence, can you explain more on what specific security aspect you are looking at local SCDF config.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an official sample, but we have another full-blown UAA based end-to-end solution that works with local, and as well the other platform choices that we support.

See: [jvalkeal/randomstuff/dataflow-uaa](https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/tree/master/dataflow-uaa).

With this, you can run UAA as a standalone process served at 8080, and SCDF+Skipper running separately it can negotiate with and use the UAA backend for authentication/authorization flows. Feel free to customize the `uaa.yaml` with desired users, roles, and the associated scopes. Once again, all this is outside of SCDF, and it comes down to how much you'd want to rely on UAA like identity providers.

Keycloak is another excellent option for a local deployment experience. I believe there's a Docker image for Keycloak.